# How to write unittests for module.exports and prototype using sinon in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have two files - **cloud utils.js** and **processor.js**. I am importing **utils.js** file in **processor.js** file

How to write unit test cases for the following code using sinon in node js application.

**utils.js**

```
exports.create = function(applicationId, password) {
  return new sdk(applicationId, password);
}

function sdk(applicationId, password) {
  this.appId = applicationId;
  this.password = password;

  this.serverUrl = "https://cloud.com";
}

sdk.prototype.processImage = function(filePath, settings, userCallback) {
  console.log('here at processImage');
}
```

**processor.js**

```
import CloudUtils from '../lib/sdk';

export default class CLOUD {

  constructor() {}

  getCloudData = async(payload) => {
    var sdk = CloudUtils.create(appId, password);
    sdk.processImage(input, settings, this.uploadCompleted);

  }
}
```

Now, I have to write test cases for my `getCloudData()` method of **processor.js** file and spy `sdk.processImage()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a tough time running your code with babel so, used non-ES code. The test is to check if the processImage has been called at least once and if yes, to assert whether the returned value is 'cloud'.

To make the test pass, just pass the value 'cloud' in the stub call.

// a.js

```
var B=require('./b');
class CLOUD {
getCloudData(){
        var b = new B();
        return b.processImage();
    }    
}

module.exports = CLOUD;
```

// b.js

```
class cloudutils {
processImage(){
        return 'cloud';
    }}

module.exports = cloudutils;
```

// Test file

```
   var A=require('./a'),B=require('./b')
   var sinon=require('sinon');
   var assert=require('assert');
   describe("Test", () => {

    var InstanceOfB;
    var InstanceOfA;
    beforeEach(() => {
        InstanceOfB = new B();
        InstanceOfA = new A();
    });

    it('should call processImage at least once', () => {
        sinon.stub(B.prototype, 'processImage', () => 'mock');
        let res = InstanceOfA.getCloudData();

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(B.prototype.processImage);
        assert.equal(res,'cloud');
    });
});
```

[image: Test result]